# Implement show more and show less buttons seperately

Tags: angular

I am trying to add a show more and a show less button separately.

I have an `ngFor` that displays a list of results

```
<div *ngFor="let item of (showMore ? searchFormData.cities : (searchFormData.cities|slice:0:15)); let i = index;">                
        <div>
            {{ item.name}}
        </div>                
</div>
```

Then I have 2 button as follows

```
<button type="button" (click)="showMore">{{'lbl.showMore'|translate}}</button>
<button type="button" (click)="!showMore">{{'lbl.showLess'|translate}}</button>
```

I know this can be done with one button with `(click)="more = !more"` but my requirement is to have 2 buttons.

Anyone know how I can go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change value of `showMore` on button click

```
<button type="button" (click)="showMore = true;">{{'lbl.showMore'|translate}}</button>
<button type="button" (click)="showMore = false;">{{'lbl.showLess'|translate}}</button>
```